# C# how to persist project .settings data between installs

Tags: c#, oneclick

I'm using .settings files in the Properties folder to persist User data. However, these files are reset to the default settings on each upgrade of software (one-click).

Is there a way of persisting the data between upgrades?

Comment: Do you mean the settings file is replaced even if it was modified after the initial install? Which setup tech are you using?

Comment: Using Visual Studio Community 2015.  One-click publishing using the IDE.

Comment: To be clear, you're correctly applying a version number to you ClickOnce installer and your Settings file has the settings scoped as User?